# Making WPF navigation dynamic - using an XML file?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, navigation

I'm working on the navigation part of a desktop application, and have a bit of a problem. The request is that the navigation should be dynamic, so that you can, for instance, switch orders of the views without having to recompile (and ideally also adding a view without recompiling).

Currently I'm using an XML to define which windows to display, which header it should have and how the footer should look like. Here's how the XML looks now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ArrayOfViewState xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ViewState ViewName="WelcomeView" Header="Welcome to the Application" FooterButton1="Quit" FooterButton2="Back" FooterButton3="Next" />
  <ViewState ViewName="LicenseView" Header="Licence Agreement" FooterButton1="Quit" FooterButton2="Back" FooterButton3="Next" />
  <ViewState ViewName="LoginView" Header="Log in" FooterButton1="Quit" FooterButton2="Back" FooterButton3="Next" />
  <ViewState ViewName="InstallationView" Header="Installing..." FooterButton1="Cancel" FooterButton2="None" FooterButton3="Next" />
  <ViewState ViewName="UpdateView" Header="Updating..." FooterButton1="Cancel" FooterButton2="None" FooterButton3="Next" />
  <ViewState ViewName="FinishedView" Header="Finished!" FooterButton1="None" FooterButton2="None" FooterButton3="Finish" />
</ArrayOfViewState>
```

And when I match this in the code it looks like this (viewState.View is of type UserControl):

```
...
case "WelcomeView":
  viewState.View = new WelcomeView();
...
```

As you can see I use the ViewName property in the XML to match and create my views (they also have a ViewModel, but that is taken care through XAML and the MVVM Light ViewModel Locator).

This solution technically allows the navigation to be changed somewhat without recompiling (for example you can shuffle the order any way you like), but there must be a better way to handle this than matching a string property. I've tried looking into serializing the User Control so that I could just load it along with the other properties, but so far I've had no luck. Any ideas on how to go about and improve/change this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, there is a better way. :-)

Have a look at the [Microsoft Extensibility Framework (MEF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx). It works very well with WPF and MVVM.

It allows you to easiliy compose application parts **on-the-fly during runtine**.

In short, you mark a class you want to be loaded somewhere else with an Attribute `[Export]`:

```
[Export(typeof(ViewContainer))]
public class ViewContainer
{
   public string ViewName = "WelcomeView";
   public string Header="Welcome to the Application"

   // Do more stuff here
}
```

And in the class or assembly that should use the exported class you can load it with the `[Import]` Attribute:

```
public class ClassInOtherAssembly
{
   [ImportMany]
   internal ObservableCollection<ViewContainer> m_MyViews { get; set; }

   // Do other stuff here
}
```

Depending on the architecture that you implement it might even be sufficient to use a 1-liner (!) to assemble all imported classes (this uses a different approach than the following referenced tutorial):

```
CompositionInitializer.SatisfyImports(this);
```

**And that's it!**

(Do *not* take these examples as is, I just wanted to get to the point. I recommend using 
`Properties` instead of the `strings` and `interfaces` instead of the class export. You'll find plenty of more elegant snippets on the net. :-) )

Here you can find a tutorial to get you started:
[Getting started with Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF)](http://weblogs.asp.net/zubairahmed/archive/2009/11/29/getting-started-with-managed-extensibility-framework-mef.aspx)

Comment: Worked on this for a bit this morning to get it running, and it's an excellent solution! Thanks a lot! I was stuck in my thought-pattern with XMLs, but this is a much cleaner way of handling navigation.

Comment: @AmadeusHein: I'm glad I could help. MEF is really great for a lot purposes. Although I already worked with it in some projects for the last two years, I am just now getting really into the depths right now. I don't know why I tried to avoid MEF for so long...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use reflection?

You could use `Activator.CreateInstance` and pass in your View's string:

```
string asmName = "YourAssembly";
string typeName = "YourViewName";

object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(asmName, typeName).Unwrap() as UserControl;
```